# Nautilus is not showing the full or folder file names

Tags: nautilus, filename

[image: name too long]

When my folder location is too long, I can't view the full file or folder names. Double clicking on the name field or in between name and size doesn't work either.

Comment: you can try dragging the this bar | between the name and the size columns to give bigger space to the name (drag it to the right)

Comment: @MinaMichael My point was that it doesn't work. I can't drag it to make it bigger because it would then take up more than the window size.

Comment: well then you can shrink the location column before expanding the name column

Comment: I can't shrink  the location folder because the name is too long, it won't shrink while there's room for it. Why don't you try it with a long location name?

Comment: I noticed that I don't have the location column in the first place! XD how did you get it? :D

Comment: It is in the Nautilus preferneces, in list view. I think he got it that big by creating a REALLY long location name, @MinaMichael.

Comment: you're right! now I have your same problem

Comment: By the way, I only made that long folder to demonstrate the problem. I have a shortcut in my Home that leads to another partition that tends to create *very* long names, but I didn't want to show all my folder names and stuff publicly.

Comment: I noticed @ike - good thinking =)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing would be to go to preferences:
[image: Preferences]

and remove the 'Location column:
[image: List Columns]

I have encountered this problem myself, and it can be rather annoying...